# Angularjs select list not initialize default value

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 select lists:

```
<select class="input-large" ng-model="bu.box.categoryId" ng-change="getSubCats()">
   <option ng-repeat="cat in cats" value="{{cat.id}}">{{cat.name}}</option>
</select>

 <select class="input-large" ng-model="bu.box.subCategoryId">
    <option ng-repeat="subcat in subCats" value="{{subcat.id}}">{{subcat.name}}</option>
</select>
```

The object `bu`, `subcats` is injected to my controller from resolve and exists before bindings is render and `cats` i get from local storage:

```
$stateProvider.state('box',
            {
                url: '/box-card/:id',
                templateUrl: '/partials/main.module/contollers/box.html?v=' + global_app_version,
                controller: 'BoxController as boxCtrl',
                resolve: {
                    Box: function ($stateParams, httpService) {
                        return httpService.getBox({ boxid: $stateParams.id });
                    }
                }
            })
```

Controller variables initialization look like this:

```
function boxController($scope, localStorageService, httpService, $state, appData, uiGridConstants, $modal, helpersService, $stateParams, $sce, Box) {
        $scope.bu = Box.data.bu;
        $scope.cats = localStorageService.get("cats");
        $scope.subCats = Box.data.currentSubCats;
............

var controllers = angular.module('app.controllers');
controllers.controller('BoxController', boxController);
```

The problem is, when the select lists is rendered, they not initialized correctly,
The first option is selected instead of relevant initialization by `ng-model`.
What happen here? Why is not working correctly?
I checked all variables in debug, all fine... Need help here.

Comment: You should use `ng-options` instead of `ng-repeat` this should resolve the issue. [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

Comment: <select ng-options="cat.name for cat in cats track by cat.id" class="input-large" ng-model="bu.box.categoryId" ng-change="getSubCats()">  This not solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to solve the problem with [ng-selected](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected).

Comment: I added ng-selected to options like this: <option ng-repeat="cat in cats" ng-selected="{{bu.box.categoryId == cat.id ? 'selected' : ''}}" value="{{cat.id}}">{{cat.name}}</option>    This put ng-selected="selected" on correct option. But still first option from select list is selected

Comment: I think it should be  <option ng-repeat="cat in cats" ng-selected="bu.box.categoryId === cat.id" value="{{cat.id}}">{{cat.name}}</option>

Comment: You are right! It works now. It steel interesting why ng-model not initialize default value, but thanks all works fine now :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [$scope.$apply()](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html) .

From the article:

> If you write any code that uses Ajax without $http, or listens for
> events without using Angular’s ng-* listeners, or sets a timeout
> without $timeout, you should wrap your code in $scope.$apply

It looks like exactly your case. `Box` is updated in a background request and angular listeners do not know that it was updated.

## UPD1

Also Just noticed that the problem could hide here
`$scope.bu` is initialized before `$scope.cats` so model actually tries to match a still empty list of options.

## upd2

just noticed in the comment that `ng-options` binding was a bit off.
try using

```
<select ng-options="cat.name for cat.id in cats track by cat.id" class="input-large" ng-model="bu.box.categoryId" ng-change="getSubCats()">
```

Comment: Maksym Stepanenko thanks for reply. $scope.$Apply() not help here. Also i tried to move initialization of $scope.bu after $scope.subCats and $scope.cats, and this is not help

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class="input-large" ng-model="bu.box.categoryId" ng-init="cat = cats[0]" ng-change="getSubCats()">
   <option ng-repeat="cat in cats" value="{{cat.id}}">{{cat.name}}</option>
</select>

 <select class="input-large" ng-model="bu.box.subCategoryId" ng-init="subcat = subCats[0]">
    <option ng-repeat="subcat in subCats" value="{{subcat.id}}">{{subcat.name}}</option>
</select>
```

I use in my project `ng-init` like `ng-init="subcat = subCats[0]"` 
change the `subCats[0]` and `cats[0]` for your init values